# Advertising new publisher after first spin in rosserial_windows

Tags: rosnode, rosserial, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies for the stupid question, but I'm still trying to grasp the basic concepts of rosnodes.

Is it possible to advertise a new publisher after the first spin? I'm currently using rosserial_windows and advertising a "late" publisher/topic results in a "Received message with unrecognized topic" warning and the new topic does not show in rostopic list. Is this a built-in limitation of ros nodes?

Just to be clear here's the order of execution:

1. Initialize connection
2. Advertise publishers/services
3. spinOnce
4. Publish a message + spinOnce (x 100)
5. Advertise new publisher + spinOnce
6. New topic does not show up, throws warning:  "Received message with unrecognized topic"

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275014/advertising-new-publisher-after-first-spin-in-rosserial_windows/) by [prnthp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32506/prnthp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-05**:
Not an answer, but please realise that you cannot consider anything `rosserial` as representative of the "basic concepts of rosnodes". `rosserial` implements a specialised subset, and has to deal with the restrictions of resource constrained platforms, which has led to some design decisions that ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-05**:
.. resulted in sometimes rather different behaviour and API.

Creating publishers and subscribers can be done at any time in 'normal ROS', but `rosserial` might have to do some special initialisation that requires a specific temporal ordering.

**Comment by [prnthp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32506/prnthp/) on 2017-11-05**:
Thank you! That clears up a lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To anyone who stumbles upon this question:

The node_handle class in `rosserial_windows` has a method called `negotiateTopics()` that is called only once (the first spin), not quite sure why. Simply calling the method `negotiateTopics()` after advertising a new publisher or subscriber tells `rosserial_python`'s `message_info_service` to add the new topics!

---

Originally posted by [prnthp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32506/prnthp/) with karma: 16 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:\

> not quite sure why

probably because it incurs some overhead which you'd want to avoid when negotiation is not needed anymore.

**Comment by [prnthp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32506/prnthp/) on 2017-11-06**:
What I meant was, why it is not called every time a new publisher or subscriber is created (maintaining a list, perhaps?). However, rosserial is designed for the arduino and I can see how the topics are only setup in `setup()` only once.